# query optimizer operator choice - nested loops vs hash match (or merge)

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-execution-plan

One of my stored procedures was taking too long execute. Taking a look at query execution plan I was able to locate the operation taking too long. It was a nested loop physical operator that had outer table (65991 rows) and inner table (19223 rows). On the nested loop it showed estimated rows = 1,268,544,993 (multiplying 65991 by 19223) as below:

[image]

I read a few articles on physical operators used for joins and got a bit confused whether nested loop or hash match would have been better for this case. From what i could gather:

Hash Match - is used by optimizer when no useful indexes are available, one table is substantially smaller than the other, tables are not sorted on the join columns. Also hash match might indicate more efficient join method (nested loops or merge join) could be used.

**Question:** Would hash match be better than nested loops in this scenario?

Thanks

Comment: Please post the query. You can always use query hints to force a particular join type and join order and compare the output of `SET STATISTICS IO ON;SET STATISTICS TIME ON;` for both (Assuming that the Join is actually an equi join so that hash join is even suitable?)

Comment: You shoul replace "Clustered Index Scan" to seek and show your script.

Comment: If you ever come back to stackoverflow some day, it would be nice if you chose an answer. :)

Answer (score 27):

ABSOLUTELY. A hash match would be a huge improvement. Creating the hash on the smaller 19,223 row table then probing into it with the larger 65,991 row table is a much smaller operation than the nested loop requiring 1,268,544,993 row comparisons.

The only reason the server would choose the nested loops is that it badly underestimated the number of rows involved. Do your tables have statistics on them, and if so, are they being updated regularly? Statistics are what enable the server to choose good execution plans.

If you've properly addressed statistics and are still having a problem you could force it to use a HASH join like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM
   TableA A -- The smaller table
   LEFT HASH JOIN TableB B -- the larger table
```

Please note that the moment you do this it will also force the join order. This means you have to arrange all your tables correctly so that their join order makes sense. Generally you would examine the execution plan the server already has and alter the order of your tables in the query to match. If you're not familiar with how to do this, the basics are that each "left" input comes first, and in graphical execution plans, the left input is the *lower* one. A complex join involving many tables may have to group joins together inside parentheses, or use `RIGHT JOIN` in order to get the execution plan to be optimal (swap left and right inputs, but introduce the table at the correct point in the join order).

It is generally best to avoid using join hints and forcing join order, so do whatever else you can first! You could look into the indexes on the tables, fragmentation, reducing column sizes (such as using `varchar` instead of `nvarchar` where Unicode is not required), or splitting the query into parts (insert to a temp table first, then join to that).

Comment: 3 years later, but you just helped me solve a problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Was the problem statistics, or did you just have to roll out the join hints and forced join order?

Comment: 5-1/2 years later and this solved a major problem for us too.  Thanks!  In our case, the "left" side of our query was the result of a recursive CTE. We discovered that the QO will always grossly underestimate row counts in recursion results, so when we were writing a subquery, the server was choosing nested loops, thinking the left would be only 3 rows. In reality, after recursing, it was over 10,000 rows.  This post prompted me to rewrite that one spot as an explicit join... and a 75-second query became a 3-second query. :-)

Comment: @JohnM.Black Just remember that join hints force join order. You'd best include a comment explaining that adding more tables to the query could be detrimental. Consider inserting to a temp table instead. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 10):

I would not recommend trying to "fix" the plan by forcing the hints in one direction or another. Instead, you need to look to your indexes, statistics and the TSQL code to understand why you have a Table spool loading up 1.2billion rows from 19000.